# Problem getting coordinates of cursor on mousemove function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've faced a problem on my project: an image that follows the mouse inside a div.

Now, I took the coordinates of the cursor with my component and make the image follow them, but i just can't figure out why sometimes the coordinates jump from the actual position to the coordinates 0;0 or in proximity of them.

**game.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.css']
})
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {

  x: any;
  y: any;
  left: any;
  top: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Getting element from HTML
    const ship = document.getElementById('spaceship');
    const space = document.getElementById('space');
    // Listener for mousmove
    space.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
      // Taking x and y coordinates
      this.x = e.offsetX;
      this.y = e.offsetY;
      console.log('X -> ' + this.x + '|Y -> ' + this.y);
      this.left = 'left: ' + this.x + 'px';
      this.top = 'top: ' + this.y + 'px';
      ship.style.cssText = this.left + '; ' + this.top;
    });
  }
}
```

**game.component.html**

```
<div id="space" style="height:100vh;">
<img id="spaceship" src="/assets/img/spaceship.png">
</div>
```

Here i leave the console log ->
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wYq4.png)

It seems to me that when the function is started, the variables are reset automatically, but I don't know why this happens.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unless your component gets reinitialised often, I don't see how this value would reset. For safety, though, I would avoid using `offset` values in mouse events, and focus on `client` value and calculating the offset yourself (I promise you: once any other input method is added you will be grateful, as touch doesn't come with 'offset'). But yeah, I'm not seeing anything that's could go wrong otherwise...

Comment: Thank you, i've resolved it by using for taking the coordinates `e.pageX`, this solve the problem!

Comment: Okay hold on, I realised what happened here. When hovering over the spaceship, a `mousemove` gets triggered on the spaceship and bubbles to its parent, which gave you `offsetX` from your spaceship while thinking you are on your space. Yeah, thats why using screen coordinates and calculating offsets yourself is a much safer bet.